# How to get docker work / run python in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: python, docker, jenkins-pipeline, pytest, devops

Here is the story...
i trying build a jenkins pipeline to automate a python test.

when i'm trying run 'pip install xxxx'. The jenkins built process returned pip command not found error. i notice jenkins might require python in the runtime and jenkins by default doesn't come with python.

Hence i trying to pull a docker image in pipeline.

```
added line "agent{ docker { image 'python:3.7.2' } }"
```

however docker not found error occurred during the build process
i have installed docker plugin on jenkins, but the docker error still remain...

the question is how i can make the docker work or
how i can run python in jenkins pipeline? as all i'm doing this cos i want to run python tests in jenkins pipeline.

here is the example code

```
pipeline {
    agent{ docker { image 'python:3.7.2' } }
    }

    stages {
        stage('checkout') {
          steps{
            xxxxxx
          }
        }
       
          stage('setup env') {
            steps {
              sh 'pip install -r dependencies.txt'
          }
        }

          stage('run test') {
            steps {
               sh 'pytest'
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is docker installed on the host machine?

Comment: yes. docker is installed on host machine.